# Android GraphView

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I'm trying to use the GraphView but I can't seem to have labels :/

This is my GraphView:

```
// init example series data
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
    , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
});
 
GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this , "GraphViewDemo");
graphView.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"2 days ago", "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow"});
graphView.setVerticalLabels(new String[] {"high", "middle", "low"});
graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries);
 
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(graphView);
```

And this is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I get: [image]

Big Edit!

Now the labels appear but they are too large, how can I reduce the font letter as well as the display overall ?

[image: Font appear, but too big(changed the type of graph)]

Comment: I should get the left and bottom labels, but I can't :/

Comment: you have really big text as labels for your graphview

Comment: how can I reduce the display ?

Comment: I tried graphview only once for about 2 hours couldnot get it to work as I wanted it to. Also the sample app was also not so good so I didnot use it. As for the labels graphview doc says that it can show labels correctly as per the magnification of the view. Dont take my word for it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be with your text being white color. Just try

graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);

The size of text could be altered as follows...
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setTextSize(11);

Comment: Thank you very much! Now how can I reduce the display ? As well as the letter font ?

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)